# Did Mohammad Ali Jinnah in 1945 say, “Muslims who are opposing Pakistan will spend the rest of their lives proving loyalty to India”?

Tags: politics, quotes, india, pakistan, muslims

A widely-retweeted [Dec 12 2019 tweet by @TonyAshai](https://twitter.com/tonyashai/status/1205001598759391232) reads

> Mohomad Ali Jinnah said in 1945, “Muslims who are opposing #Pakistan will spend rest of their lives proving loyalty to India” and #Modi and #Amitshah validated it 2019 by their actions in #Kashmir.

Did Mohammad Ali Jinnah say this?

Comment: Hard to say. It's not on Wikiquote, but even what's there is a bit contradictory, suggesting  he might have changed his views over time... On one hand "In due course of time, Hindus will cease to be Hindus and Muslims will cease to be Muslims, not in a religious sense because that is the personal faith of an individual, but in a political sense as citizens of one state." (1947)

Comment: On the other hand (1940) " it is a dream that the Hindus and Muslims can ever evolve a common nationality... To yoke together two such nations under a single state, one as a numerical minority and the other as a majority, must lead to growing discontent and final destruction of any fabric that may be so built for the government of such a state."

Comment: Someone asked a very similar question in 2017 on Quora https://www.quora.com/Did-Mohammed-Ali-Jinnah-tell-the-Muslims-who-want-to-stay-in-India-that-they-would-have-to-prove-their-patriotism-to-India-for-the-rest-of-their-lives so the belief that Jinnah said this didn't start with the 2019 tweet.

Comment: I found using Twitter search that the earliest tweet with this quote dates to June 2017. From the very beginning, a lot of the tweets seem very similar and robot-like.

Comment: @Avery can you link to the June 2017 tweet?

Comment: @DavePhD, I don't see how the date is important. I just wanted to check if the quotation was authentic. I.e., if Jinnah really said that or not.

Comment: @DavePhD Here is the earliest use of this quote on twitter  https://twitter.com/sumiya_as/status/880316487977754624 and second oldest https://twitter.com/Qureshi__/status/880281372337852417